# Run testng test in Git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, bash, testng, pre-commit-hook

How would I write a bash script that will run as a git pre-commit hook to fail if a specific testng test fails? I currently run my testng tests through maven surefire like this:

```
mvn clean test -Dtest="MyTestName"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `pre-commit` hook returns non-zero, then the commit is aborted before it even starts. In a script for a bourne style shell (e.g. sh, ksh, zsh, bash, etc.), by default the return value of the last command run is the return value of the script. As I understand it `mvn clean test` should return non-zero on failure, so your script should be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn clean test -Dtest="MyTestName"
```

Then just name it `pre-commit` in your `.git/hooks/` directory in your repo and run `chmod ug+x` on it to make sure it can be executed.

Comment: Thanks let me give this a try