# Running maven command after git pull with git hook

Tags: git, maven, githooks

i am working with git, and i would like to run maven command after each git pull command
i found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100369/run-testng-test-in-git-pre-commit-hook)

so i created a file called `post-merge` based on this [link](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/githooks/)

and it looks like that

```
#!/bin/sh
cd web
mvn exec:java -e -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.web.build.db.MigrateDBSqlGenerator" -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false
```

The git hook file is stored here:

```
C:\dato\master\.git\hooks
```

And here i executed my git pull command:

```
User@USER-PC /c/dato/master (DAT-21865-flyway-infra)
$ git pull
Password for 'https://xxxxxxxxx@bitbucket.org':
Updating cc1efa0..4ba349a
Fast-forward
 web/pom.xml | 21 ++++++++++++++++-----
 1 file changed, 16 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

But it looks like it didnt run my git hook, what am i missing here ?

Comment: did you set `execute` flag on the file? (`chmod +x ..`)

Comment: Its a windows machine

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513548/git-hook-post-merge-not-called-after-pull-although-called-after-merge